# Upgrading older Mura sites, changing from ACF to Lucee, and changing OS 2008r2 to 2016

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, mura

I've inherited an older Mura client (client1.com) running 5.6x and I also have a more current client (also inherited) running 7.1x (client2.com).

First, I have very very very little experience with Mura.

The older client (client1.com) running 5.6x doesn't have the ability to create a site bundle but the one running 7.1x (client2.com) does.

I'm having issues migrating client1.com to the new server but client2.com moved over just fine. My question is can I create a "space" for clien1.com using client2.com mura installation and then just import the database and files for the site?

Comment: You might get your answers quicker using Mura's support options: https://www.getmura.com/support/community-support/ The slack channel might be the better option of those.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianJ.Moreno, I'll check that out, too.